# Excel, 100% stacked bar graph, not showing correctly?

Tags: excel, graph, percentage

Ok so I have a stacked 100% graph that is clearly not right...
As you can see the axis is visable and the 40% in the first column is going up to the 50% mark of the axis, how and why? Or more importantly, how do I fix it?!

[image]

NB this is the same graph by normal stacked:

[image]

Comment: 1439 = 51% of the total of that category 
Not sure which percentages you are showing or wanting to show, but the labels inside the bars are all wrong
(816 = 28.9% and 565 = 20%)

Comment: Ahhh, obviously! Totally myfault sorry for bothering you!

Comment: In case anyone needs an expolanation the graph started as a count of accounts and the % was showing the % of accounts not the % of debt.